# How to bypass the ISP router for port forwarding?

Tags: linux, port-forwarding

My ISP is blocking access to my router, so when I enter the default gateway IP in the address bar I got nothing. The problem is that I need port forwarding to allow global access to my server.

if I connect my own wi-fi router to the ISP router (with a LAN cable, say on bridged LAN1 port) can I manage port forwarding on my router (bypassing the ISP router)? I mean, if ISP agrees to bridge LAN1 port, will I actually bypass the ISP router, or it will still block the global access to my server? The last option is to call the ISP and to ask them to do port forwarding for me, but I doubt if they agree.

I've found solution in bypassing the ISP router with [ngork](https://superuser.com/questions/1258093/set-up-a-web-server-behind-a-carrier-grade-nat). It works great and I don't need to contact the ISP or buying any additional router.

Comment: If your WAN side IP address is in `100.64.0.0/10` prefix, then your ISP is doing CGNAT and you cannot get port forwarding from public internet. You need to ask your ISP how to get port forward working.

Comment: You have a residential network. Your residential contract prohibits you running services to the Internet, so your ISP does not care that CGN breaks that for you. You need to get a business contract.

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you change and go to a new ISP, if possible.

This seem like an boring answer, but the reality is that you are locked with whatever your ISP deem to a internet service to you.

IMO, leaching you connection like that is not honest.

Note that all ISP have some rules about port-forwarding and will block some specifics one like 80 or 443, but not allowing any is kind of weird.

This is the first time I see that. At least for a while. Like... 20 years.

Comment: This is not a question about a business ISP connection, so (1) it's off topic, and (2) they are probably using so-called "carrier grade NAT" which makes inbound IPv4 connections impossible. It's best to avoid answering off-topic questions.